# Pretty Printer for Oracle TNS entries?

Tags: oracle, pretty-print, tns

I've got some TNS entries formatted as single long lines.  Any pretty printers available?  Here's an example of what I've currently got.

```
(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = trac403-vip.pixar.com)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = tmpltest) (INSTANCE_NAME = tmpltest3)))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here you go :)

```
(DESCRIPTION = 
  (ADDRESS = 
    (PROTOCOL = TCP)
    (HOST = trac403-vip.pixar.com)(PORT = 1521)
  ) 
  (CONNECT_DATA = 
    (SERVER = DEDICATED) 
    (SERVICE_NAME = tmpltest) 
    (INSTANCE_NAME = tmpltest3)
  )
)
```